# MySQL Search Query for WordPress Database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, search

I am currently building a mobile(Android) app that is a search engine for products. The products information, is currently stored in a WordPress eCommerce store(WooCommerce). I have added 5 sample products to this store for testing purposes.

I currently have the search function working inside the app. The MySQL query used for this search is as follows:

```
SELECT a.*, b.guid AS img_url 
FROM wp_posts AS a 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS b ON a.ID = b.post_parent 
WHERE a.post_type='product' 
AND a.post_title LIKE '%$search%'
```

Now, when I search for something like "sample", I get my search results with all of the products that contain the word sample in it's title.

However, if one of those products has more than one image attached to it. I get results for as many images that are attached to the product.(see screenshot below)

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/M7Ap

If anyone could help me with this, so that I don't get the multiple results for the one post. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the question is:  when you have a product with more than one image, which one do you want?  Once you define that, then you can use this technique: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: I just want it to show the featured image.

Comment: Correction, I want to show the product + featured image. Exactly what you see in the screen shot. But just the original post and featured image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about which result, but just want one per post, can you not just use GROUP BY?

Comment: Well, I want it to show the original post with the featured image. Those are the results I get when the product only has a featured image.

Comment: sorry, I don't know the structure of the wp_posts, but could it be that the images are stored as wp_post records with a post_parent of the post they are attached to?

Comment: Yes, the images are stored as the corresponding post but with the "post_type = attachment". However, when I run the above query in phpMyAdmin it shows them all with "post_type = product".

Comment: as I said, just add a GROUP BY (ID) at the end of the query, that should do.

Comment: Dude, I love you! Was that too far? Um, thank you very much! :)

Comment: nah, that's alright, you can show your love accepting the answer :)